# Cypress cy.viewport() not rendering content wrapped in react-responsive MediaQuery components

Tags: reactjs, responsive, cypress

I'm Working on a project that uses `react-responsive` to render different content for different devices. I'm trying to write tests in Cypress using cy.viewport() to ensure that the correct device-specific content renders. I'm calling `cy.viewport()` in the `beforeEach()` block of the spec. I can see that Cypress is using the prescribed viewport setting in the browser.  However, content wrapped in the `react-responsive` `<MediaQuery />` components is not rendering at all in the Cypress tests.

The content renders properly outside of cypress. This has been tested manually on actual devices and by using the device emulation feature of the Chrome dev tools.

The only way that I'm able to get Cypress to render this content is if I open the dev tools in the browser window that Cypress is controlling and manually activate device emulation (which sort of defeats the purpose of `cy.viewport()`)

Has anyone else run into this?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I found a solution. Basically, I changed the media queries I was using to omit the word `device`. The attached screen grab shows the diff of the constants file where the media queries are declared:

[image]

Previously, I had `min-device-width` and `max-device-width`. These media queries worked perfectly in the Chrome device emulator and on actual tablets and phones via ngrok. However, they did not work with Cypress. BY changing the syntax to `min-width` and `max-width` it now works in dev tools, on devices, and on Cypress.